# dojo query to get parents of all inputs

Tags: dojo

I'm used to the jQuery style of selecting, which would be fairly easy in this case

```
$("tbody td:has(input)").click(...);
```

But dojo seems to be using only regular CSS selectors, which means I can't get a parent element.
I've tried to do this:

```
dojo.query("tbody td input").parentNode.onclick(...);
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: dojo.query returns a NodeList, so you'd need to reference an element like [0] before using Node methods, or use a solution like jrburke's below

Comment: No, because the whole point to to apply an event listener to multiple elements at once. The solution below works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
dojo.query("tbody td:contains(input)").onclick()
```

Comment: wow. I can't believe I didn't remember `:contains`.. thanks, man (:

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Dojo have a module to extend [dojo.query](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/query.html#dojo-query): [traverse](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/NodeList-traverse.html). It contains also **parent** function.